# How do you specify or read the position of the main app window with guizero?

Tags: python, user-interface, position, window

I need to specify, or just read, the position (x and y coordinates of the top left corner) of the main app window in guizero.
Apparently the App object does not have x and y positions properties that I can set or read.
I found on this forum a solution for this issue with TkInter but not guizero.

My goal is actually to be able to tell the mouse position within the app window. I can tell the mouse position with respect of the entire screen with the event data **display_x** and **display_y** and those change if I move the window around but I could use these values if I could account for the position of the window on the screen so, how do I find that out?

The event data x and y, which are meant precisely to return the relative x and y position of the mouse within a widget, will NOT work IF that particular region of the window is "covered" by a widget like a text or a button.

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3

event_data.display_x = x position of the mouse on the entire display

event_data.x = x position of the mouse on a widget. 
Cannot use for the app window if that position is "covered" by a widget

Comment: From [Project description - guizero](https://pypi.org/project/guizero/) *"guizero only requires tkinter"*, therefore any `tkinter` solution should work. Add a [mcve] to your Question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

Apparently you can use tkinter methods and properties directly on guizero objects.
As it happens, the **geometry** property returns a string that contains the window coordinates.

so this is an example:

```
from guizero import App, PushButton

#___________________________________
def appos(event_data):
    """ Print the coordinates of the Window position,
        of the mouse position on the screen
        and of the mouse position within the window"""

    # Absolute mouse position on display
    mouse_x, mouse_y = (event_data.display_x), (event_data.display_y)

    # tk.geometry() returns the size and coordinates of a window in a string
    wincord = (app.tk.geometry()).split("+")[1:] # Discards size 

    # Coordinates of (top left corner) of window
    wincord_x, wincord_y = int(wincord[0]), int (wincord[1])

    # Relative mouse position within the window
    mouse_rel_x = mouse_x - wincord_x
    mouse_rel_y = mouse_y - wincord_y

    print ("Window position on display: ", wincord_x, wincord_y)
    print ("Mouse position on entire display: ", mouse_x, mouse_y)
    print ("Mouse position in window: ", mouse_rel_x, mouse_rel_y)
    print()
#_________________________________

app = App(layout="grid")

app.when_clicked = appos # Call the function that prints the positions

# Creates a list of lists (kinda a 2-dimension array) with 
# placeholders to be filled with buttons
bt = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

# creates an array of 8x8 buttons and arrange them on the window
for x in range (8):
    for y in range (8):
        bt[x][y] = PushButton(app, text= str(x)+str(y), grid= [x, y])
        # bt[x][y].when_clicked = clicked # For future use

app.display()
```

As you can see, by clicking anywhere on the window, you get the correct mouse position within the window even if it is covered by buttons!